# What does it mean that $\sin(t) = 0$ for $t = 0$ or $\pi$ mod $2\pi$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

My prof wrote $\sin(t) = 0$ for $t = 0$ for $\pi$ mod $2\pi$ on the board

Is this some fancy pants way to say that $\sin(t) = 0$, at points $0, \pi, 2\pi...$

Can someone explain how $\pi$ mod $2\pi$ turn into all points where $\sin(t) = 0$?

Comment: Are you sure that's how he wrote it? It looks like you have some typo.

Comment: Maybe he meant $t=0$ OR $pi$ mod $2\pi$? At any rate, it seems like you know when $\sin(t) = 0$ so I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your prof says $\sin(t)=0$ iff
$$
\frac{t}{2\pi}\in\mathbb{Z}\quad\text{or}\quad\frac{t-\pi}{2\pi}\in\mathbb{Z}
$$
which, as you put, is a "fancy pants way" to say $\sin(t)=0$ iff $t=k\pi$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

Writing $a = b \pmod m$ means, by definition, that the difference $a - b$ is divisible by $m$ (although one typically writes $a \equiv b \pmod m$).

Then, saying $x = 0 \pmod {2\pi}$ really means that $x - 0$, that is $x$, is divisible by $2\pi$; it's a multiple of $2 \pi$.

If you write out $x = \pi \pmod {2\pi}$, you'll find that this is satisfied by all *odd* integer multiples of $\pi$.

It's just a (sometimes) convenient shorthand to write out arithmetic sequences (although it could have been more tersely stated, in this case, as $x \equiv 0 \pmod \pi)$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, if $\sin t = 0$ then $t \in I(2\pi)$, that is, $t = \pi + 2k\pi , k \in \mathbb Z$, in other words

$$t - \pi \in I(2\pi) =\{\ldots, -2\pi, 0,1\dot\, 2\pi, 3\dot\, 2\pi, \ldots\} \iff t \equiv \pi \mod 2\pi $$